# Link only visible for certain users?

Tags: php

How would I make a hyperlink from my product table visible for a session user that is subscribed in my user table while a non-subscribed user can not see the link from the product table?

This is the current code I have.

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "", "");
mysql_select_db("",$db);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM inventoryTable",$db);
$query="select * from users where sub = 'yes'";
$id=mysql_query($query);
echo "<TABLE style=\"background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 10px solid A4A4A4;\">";
echo"<TR><TD><B>Title</B>
<TD><B>Authors First Name</B>
<TD><B>Authors Last Name</B>
<TD><B>ISBN</B><TD>
<B>Publisher</B>
<TD><B>Course Number</B>
<TD><B>Source</B></TR>";
while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<TR><TD>".$myrow["title"].
"<TD>".$myrow["authorsFirst"].
"<TD>".$myrow["authorsLast"].
"<TD>".$myrow["ISBN"].
"<TD>".$myrow["publisher"].
"<TD>".$myrow["courseNum"];
If($_SESSION['username']== '$id')
{"<td>".$myrow["source"];
} else {
    echo "<TD>"."Please subscribe to View";
}
echo "</TABLE>";

}
?>
```

My if statement is always returning false. I am wanting the users from my user table that have a 'yes' in their sub field to be able to view the source field from my inventoryTable.

Comment: what you have to check here in if

Comment: you are missing something in table please check

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Answer (score 2):

```
If($_SESSION[username]== subscribed Id or name){ $myrow["link"]}else{blank }
```